# Flickity slider on Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, flickity

I'm trying to setup the Flickity slider on drupal 8 and it doesn't seem to work and support on setting this up is almost no were to be found.

I got the slider loading 2 images but it doesn't seem to work (not sliding but I go the left and right arrows). If any body had done this successfully please let me know the setup.

Below is the HTML that is put out on the page from drupal.

```
<div class="flickity-viewport" style="height: 1054.68px;">
<div class="flickity-slider" style="right: 0px; transform: translateX(0%);">
<div class="gallery-cell item-0 is-selected" style="position: absolute; right: 0%;"> 
<div class="views-field views-field-field-slider-image"><div class="field-content">
<img src="/drupm/sites/default/files/2017-10/bg5.jpg" alt="bg3" typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-fluid" width="1920" height="1080">
</div>
<div class="gallery-cell item-1" style="position: absolute; right: 100%;"> 
<div class="views-field views-field-field-slider-image">
<div class="field-content">
<img src="/drupm/sites/default/files/2017-10/bg3_0.jpg" alt="bg1" typeof="foaf:Image" class="img-fluid" width="1920" height="1080">
</div></div>
</div></div></div>
```

Comment: What does your browser console show? Are there JS errors? What are the click event listeners on your arrows? You can get this from the Elements panel.

Comment: hi @chaky have you used it with Paragraphs?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip on checking the console which I totally forgot.

I installed flickity (v.8.x-2.2) with bootstrap 4(v.4.0.0-beta.2) and they don't seem to do well together. Downgraded Bootstrap to 3(v.3.3.7) and it works properly.

I'm staying away from Bootstrap 4 till it become stable.